# how to cast comboBox object to Color object

Tags: java, object, colors, combobox, casting

I am trying to do the following cast with no luck so far - the compiler comliles fine, but I have exception at run time.
I am trying to paint the frame contentPane with a color chosen from a comboBox.
Here is my code, which constructs the JComboBox object:

```
public  RgbComboBoxFrame() {

    colorComboBox = new JComboBox();
    colorComboBox.addItem("RED");
    colorComboBox.addItem("GREEN");
    colorComboBox.addItem("BLUE");
    colorComboBox.setEditable(true);
    listener = new AddListener();
    paintContentPane();
    createPanel();
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
}
```

Here is my the method.Here I am trying to resolve the issue with the casting:

```
private void paintContentPane(){
    Color c = (Color)colorComboBox.getSelectedItem();

    getContentPane().setBackground(c);
}
```

Comment: Your colorComboBox does not return a Color object? Do you know if it returns Color objects?

Comment: I am not sure, here is my code that constructs the JComboBox object in my constructor, isn't it object of type String ?:

        colorComboBox = new JComboBox();
        colorComboBox.addItem("RED");
        colorComboBox.addItem("GREEN");
        colorComboBox.addItem("BLUE");
        colorComboBox.setEditable(true);

Comment: If that is what you are doing, how do you expect that it shall automatically convert String to a Color object at runtime?

Comment: I am trying to cast the comboBox object into Color object, I don't know any options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this:

```
Color c = (Color)colorComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

Then you must add actual `Color` objects to the combo box. Casting is only a way to say to the compiler "I know what I am doing, so let this pass". It let you write code where the types does not necessarily match at compile time, but you know it will be runtime. (In simple words). You want to write this instead:

```
colorComboBox = new JComboBox();
colorComboBox.addItem(Color.red);
colorComboBox.addItem(Color.green);
colorComboBox.addItem(Color.blue);
colorComboBox.setEditable(true)
```

I guess that showing toString() is not what you want so you should create a custom cell renderer.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer

Example of a custom combo box cell renderer:

```
class ColorComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel
        implements ListCellRenderer {

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {

        if (value instanceof Color) {
            Color color = (Color) value;

            if (color.equals(Color.red)) {
                setText("Red");
            } else if (color.equals(Color.green)) {
                setText("Green");
            }
        } else {
            setText(" ");
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

The logic for finding the actual name of a color object could be more advanced of course but you get the idea. Then you create an instance of the class and add it to your `ComboBox`:

```
ColorComboBoxRenderer renderer = new ColorComboBoxRenderer ();
colorComboBox.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Comment: Oh, I did't know that I can construct comboBox wity any object, not only objects of type String. Thank you! I will try that!

Comment: I will add an example of a custom `ListCellRenderer`

Comment: 10x, I am interested to see that :)

Comment: I haven't actually tested this, but it shouldn't be far from being usable:)

Comment: Thank you Knight Rider, that looks a lot complicated for me, but I will try to test it out! :)

Comment: Read the documentation that I linkedt to.